# javascript statement execution

Tags: php, javascript

Can anyone point out what might be the mistake here in this javascript. The first statement executes just fine but when i add another statement that is to be executed simultaneously, it doesn't work.

```
    echo '<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
        //<![CDATA[
      window.open(\'./index_pdf.php?'.$query_string.'\',\'Einlagerung_EV\',\'location=no,menubar=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,status=yes,toolbar=no\');
        //]]>
    </script>';
    echo'<script language = "JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
        //<![CDATA[
        window.open('./save.php?','location=no,menubar=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,status=yes');
        //]]>
        </script>';
```

Comment: What the I don't even why you no escape your apostrophes.

Comment: You can't execute things simultaneously in javascript, it's single-threaded. Btw, most pop-up-blockers will block those windows.

Comment: Just thought I would suggest using heredoc for this, it is just so much easier, cleaner, and do not have to worry so much about quote problems...

Comment: so its not possible to open two pop up windows simultaneously?well as of now for testing i have disabled the pop up blocker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are stopping the script here: `window.open('./save.php?','location=no,menubar=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,status=yes');`

Use it like this:

```
echo'<script language = "JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
    window.open(\'./save.php?\',\'location=no,menubar=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,status=yes\');
    //]]>
    </script>';
```

As you can see in the 1st example, it is using `\'`, but you are using plain `'`. Since you open the tag with `'`, you cant use that symbol inside the script unless you want to break it intentionally. The symbol `\` lets you use the quotes, without braking the script.

Comment: thanks for the correction.I managed to edit is as u told but still there is only the first statement that is getting executed and the first pop up coming up on the screen.

Comment: Well, look exactly at the 1st and 2nd example you posted. The 1st one has **3** attributes, while the second one has only **2**.

Comment: very well..i had not noticed that at all!!thanks for your help!! :)